# Access to the path denied on UNC Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have ASP.net web Application which will upload the files to a  Virtual Directory where a UNC Location.

But when I upload the file I get "Access to the path **'\SERVER NAME\Files\engyImportListTEMPLATE (1)-8Aug.xlsx' is denied."**

I have give Everyone Read\Write Permission to the UNC folder but Still the application failed to upload the file.

Note :The servers are WORKGROUP.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please give us more details: .NET Framework version, IIS version

Comment: Set up a domain would be the simplest. If you insist WORKGROUP, make sure the same user account has the same password on all machines. Otherwise, such errors are expected.

Comment: Can you post some of the code where you're trying to do I/O actions?

Comment: @Waragi Its just a File upload control with "string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
                    this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + this.FileUpload1.FileName);"

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas its .net 4.6 and IIS 10.0.14393.0

Comment: @LexLi Yes I have same User "Administrator" and with the same Password.

Comment: Please check identity on which application pool is running - that should be the user who needs privileges to access destination path

Comment: @LitteSweetSeas Thank you  Error disappeared. But Server.MapPath unable to resolve the path to Virtual Directory. let me Try and update here.

Comment: Hi All,I have figured out all the issues, But file was not uploaded. I have read some articles which say "only IIS knows where that points and I have to code the path manually in the code" Is that correct?